# How to show Assign To list for bugs work item?

Tags: testing, tfs, tfs-2015, assign

I'm a tester and my manager has add new team project to the TFS and add my user and a developer user for this team project, when I've tried to add any type of work items the list of "Assigned To" shows all the users correctly, except for the "bug work item" only, I can't assigned to any user and shows that it is not in the list of supported values. 
how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using the system build-in process template or not? Have you ever customized the Bug work item type?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the work item that you're manipulating currently in a **state** that **has a valid transition** to New. Otherwise, you will not be able to save the changes.

If you have customized the bug work item type. According to sounds like a rule in the bug workflow or field.

If you run the [witadmin exportwitd] command and export the bug work item type, look for the Assigned To Field and look at the rules on the field. Also take a look at the  section and look at the rules for the transitions.

Also take a look at this similar question on TFS2015 [Bug/Task unable to assign it to someone else than the user that creates it](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c8c91a36-83f7-4e40-9b64-0813ede440c2/bugtask-unable-to-assign-it-to-someone-else-than-the-user-that-creates-it?forum=tfsadmin), try the suggestion mentioned in the link:

> needed to give the relevant global top-level permissions for everyone
>   to view stuff
>
> Just run the below in order to grant the needed rights :

```
tfssecurity /a+ Server FrameworkGlobalSecurity GenericRead
> "[DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Valid Users" ALLOW
> /collection:http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
```